# app.yaml to send params to Dockerfile

Tags: google-app-engine, dockerfile, gcloud, app.yaml

I am deploying a binary on Google cloud flexible app engine for two different services. So I have {app-service1.yaml, Dockerfile-service1} and {app-service2.yaml, Dockerfile-service2}. And use "gcloud app deploy" command to deploy them.

Is it possible to send a param from app-service[1|2].yaml to a single Dockerfile, so that I can maintain only one Dockerfile?

I tried two things but they didn't work with "gcloud deploy" command:

1. "entrypoint:" in app.yaml -- It does not override what is set in CMD in Dockerfile.
2. "env_variables:" in app.yaml -- Dockerfile's ENV or ARG do not see any variables defined in env_variables:.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way (I can think of) to pass parameters into the docker build process while using `gcloud app deploy`.  If the dockerfiles you're using are similar, you may want to consider creating a base docker file, building a base image, and then sending it to gcr.io.  Then you can extend the base image with your other Dockerfile(s).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Justin for the reply. Then what is the use of "env_variables:" in app.yaml?  I expect it is the way to send env variable to build process or vm.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I made it working.In app.yaml, set environment variables at "env_variables:". That env variables may not be visible at image build time, but they are visible to the app at run time.